# Loop within a for loop getting ignored?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Please read edit
I have a assignment for college where I must create multiple arrays and populate them with user input for name, address, previous grade etc.
I created a "for" loop to run until 8 correct entries are given for the multiple conditions. My first condition takes the name. I have added code to stop an incorrect entry (in this case numbers and symbols and for it to stop a blank entry.

```
int studentno[]=new int[8];          //Array for student number
String studentname[]=new String[8];  //Array for student name
String studentadd[]=new String[8];   //Array for address of student
char studentgrade[]=new char[8];     //Array for previous grade
int studentass1[]=new int[8];        //Array for Computing Programming Assignment1
int studentass2[]=new int[8];        //Array for Computing Programming Assignment2
int studentexam[]=new int[8];        //Array for Computing Programming Exam

for (int i = 0;i<8;i++) {           //Creates for loop that will run 8 time 
                                    //unless an incorrect input is inputted
     studentno[i] = 37000 + (int)(Math.random() * ((38000 - 37000) + 1));     
                                    //Generates random numbers within a range I    
                                    //specified to mimic college system.

     for (int name = 0; name < studentname.length; name++) { 

         studentname[i]  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                       "Please enter Student name. \n You have entered data for "
                        +i+" students so far.");

         Pattern pno = Pattern.compile("[0-9,&%$#@!()*^]"); 
         Matcher mno = pno.matcher(studentname[i]);

         if (mno.find()) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter only letters.");
             name--;
         }
         else if (studentname[i] != null && !studentname[i].isEmpty()) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not entered any data");
             name--;
         }
```

This looks right to me but when I run the program it completely skips the second for loop and moves onto my next condition. (Which doesent contain a loop yet)
How would I fix this? I want the program to reask the condition if it is invalid without adding 1 to i or moving on to the next condition.

EDIT: Just to clarify this is the end product I hope to achieve:
for loop{
 for loop{
  ask for name
   if name is incorrect (contains number, symbol or is empty reask the question.

repeat for 6 different questions
}
repeat 8 times getting 7 correct answers for each question

EDIT EDIT: Showing full code now. My intent is to make the program take a name and move on to another duplicate loop with address then another and another. Only moving on when a correct entry is given.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. If you're never entering the loop, it's fairly clear that `studentname.length` is greater than or equal to `8`. You haven't shown where or how that gets created, but that would be why you don't enter the loop.

Comment: What is the inner loop `for (int name=studentname.length; name<8; name++)` supposed to do?  What is `studentname`, and where is it initialized?

Comment: Apoligies about the "8" I copied the loop above it. Silly mistake.

Comment: To clarify I have arrays at the start of the code. The inner loop takes a name (if correct) and stores it in the array studentname[]. After which it will be follewed by a duplicate loop asking for an address.

Comment: @user2965503 Nothing in your loop stores anything in `studentname[i]`.  Your last assignment statement `nameofstudent = studentname[i]` might be backwards.  And even if you fix that, you're calling `pno.matcher` on `studentname[i]` before it's assigned.  And I still haven't figured out what you're doing with the `name` variable; you're looping on it, but you don't use it for anything.

Comment: I'll throw up a new question showing the full code and my intended outcome.

Comment: @ajb Instead of making a new question I showed my full code and what I intend to do with it.

Comment: That explains things a bit better.  But your code asks for _each_ student name 8 times, i.e. it asks for 64 names (if there are no errors).  That can't be what you want, right?  You need to rethink your inner loop.  It should probably be a `while` loop, and possibly `while(true)` with a `break` statement somewhere in the loop.  The `name` variable serves no purpose that I can see.

Comment: You may want to re-think your design here.... this really is a terrible way to implement record-storing of any kind, and unless your assignment specifically says you have to do it this way, you may want to consider taking a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You start off in your 2nd for-loop with the studentname length, and then your conditional is if it is less than 8. So if all of your students have lenghts greater than 8, this loop will indeed get ignored. Fix this to do what you actually want it to do.

My guess is you want loop to look like this:

```
for (int name = 0; name < studentname.length; name++) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yea check your condition in your second loop

Comment: Hey, I did the code you gave and the loop did indeed work however when I entered a correct output the program crashed. I also edited my question at the end to show what I'm trying to achieve in the end.

Comment: @user2965503 I don't see anywhere in the code where `studentname[i]` is set to anything.  Does that happen above the loop, somewhere?  If so, you may need to show us a larger segment of your code.

Comment: @zgc7009 I edited the question to show full code. Sorry this is my first time posting